# How do I connect webapp VB/LINQ to a MySQL database server on a Linux

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linq

I have a programmer who is using VB and LINQ; and I have a MySQL database that is running on a linux server. My programmer tells me that:

1. he cannot connect to the MySQL database via LINQ
2. if he was able to connect then it would require all sorts of rewriting

I don't know anything about LINQ but I thought it was an ORM.  As such, any DB server that is supported should work just fine? Right?

OK, so maybe it's not an ORM... maybe it should generically connect to ODBC and render similar results?

Is there any advice out there for connecting VB+LINQ to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use an open source project like http://code2code.net/DB_Linq/index.html
or you can use Linq to NHibernate: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/16/Linq-for-NHibernate.aspx

or even InterLinq if you want to make a multi-tier setup: http://www.codeplex.com/interlinq

Comment: MEH!  I wish there was a better answer than this... but I guess I will have to settle for this one. Thanks!